# Pythonic way to group items in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collections

Consider a list of dicts:

```
items = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 9, 'c': 8},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 4},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 9},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 2}
]
```

Is there a pythonic way to extract and group these items by their `a` field, such that:

```
result = {
    1 : [{'b': 9, 'c': 8}, {'b': 5, 'c': 4}]
    2 : [{'b': 3, 'c': 1}, {'b': 7, 'c': 9}]
    3 : [{'b': 8, 'c': 2}]
}
```

References to any similar Pythonic constructs are appreciated.

Comment: Please try not to close this question. There are good answers here that aren't covered in the linked question.

Comment: Actually the method Martijn suggested in the other answer, is the core idea. Our answers have just built-up on the same idea :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(items, itemgetter('a'))}
{1: [{'a': 1, 'c': 8, 'b': 9},
     {'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 5}],
 2: [{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3},
     {'a': 2, 'c': 9, 'b': 7}],
 3: [{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 8}]}
```

If item are not in sorted order then you can either sort them and then use `groupby` or you can use `collections.OrderedDict`(if order matters) or `collections.defaultdict` to do it in O(N) time:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for item in items:
...     d.setdefault(item['a'], []).append(item)
...     
>>> dict(d.items())
{1: [{'a': 1, 'c': 8, 'b': 9},
     {'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 5}],
 2: [{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3},
     {'a': 2, 'c': 9, 'b': 7}],
 3: [{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 8}]}
```

**Update:**

I see that you only want the those keys to be returned that we didn't use for grouping, for that you'll need to do something like this:

```
>>> group_keys = {'a'}
>>> {k:[{k:d[k] for k in d.viewkeys() - group_keys} for d in g]
                                   for k, g in groupby(items, itemgetter(*group_keys))}
{1: [{'c': 8, 'b': 9},
     {'c': 4, 'b': 5}],
 2: [{'c': 1, 'b': 3},
     {'c': 9, 'b': 7}],
 3: [{'c': 2, 'b': 8}]}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** This code assumes the the data is already sorted. If it is not, we have to sort it manually

```
from itertools import groupby
print {key:list(grp) for key, grp in groupby(items, key=lambda x:x["a"])}
```

**Output**

```
{1: [{'a': 1, 'b': 9, 'c': 8}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 4}],
 2: [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 9}],
 3: [{'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 2}]}
```

To get the result in the same format you asked for,

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
a_getter, getter, keys = itemgetter("a"), itemgetter("b", "c"), ("b", "c")

def recon_dicts(items):
    return dict(zip(keys, getter(items)))

{key: map(recon_dicts, grp) for key, grp in groupby(items, key=a_getter)}
```

**Output**

```
{1: [{'c': 8, 'b': 9}, {'c': 4, 'b': 5}],
 2: [{'c': 1, 'b': 3}, {'c': 9, 'b': 7}],
 3: [{'c': 2, 'b': 8}]}
```

If the data is not `sorted` already, you can either use the `defaultdict` method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23339428/1903116), or you can use `sorted` function to sort based on `a`, like this

```
{key: map(recon_dicts, grp)
   for key, grp in groupby(sorted(items, key=a_getter), key=a_getter)}
```

**References:**

1. [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
2. [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
3. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict), [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)